# PopupWindow without XML android

Tags: android, popupwindow

need to create PopupWindow dynamically, without popup.xml.

I have few Views and need create popupWindow, which will contain pressed view

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: in android w.r.t. views whatever you do in XML can be done in java code as well.